# How multiplying probabilities works?

Tags: probability, intuition

If there are 2 independent event A and B, we find the probability of their intersection as product of their respective probability.
Though I know how it is deduced but I don't seem to find proper intuition behind it.
I don't expect any derivation. Kindly someone help.

Comment: The way I think of it:  If the two events are independent, then knowing that we have $A$ tells us nothing about $B$.  Thus if I take my entire sample, and restrict to those for which $A$ is true ($P(A)$ percent of the total) then I still expect $B$ to occur with the same probability.  Thus $P(B)$ of my subset has both properties, but that is $P(A)\times P(B)$ of the total.

Comment: Need some more clarification.

Comment: If by "how it is deduced" you mean "how it is defined", then that is how independence of two events is defined by most authors.  Why is this a useful definition?  You can certainly work out an example (e.g. flipping two coins or rolling two die) and see that it often applies in practice.  You can also look for examples where it does not apply (such as when two events are *mutually exclusive* so the probability of intersection is zero even if the product of probabilities is not).

Answer (score 0):

A and B being independent means that whether A happens or not does not alter the probability of B occurring or not. So, when A and B are independent, we basically we have that $P(A|B) = P(A)$ (this disregards the case where $P(B)=0$, but for convenience sake let's assume $P(B) >0$).

Now, in general we say that the probability for the intersection of A and B to happen is to have one happen multiplied by the other the happen as well *given* that the first one happens (so basically: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B|A)$ . But we just saw that when they are independent, then $P(B|A) = P(B)$, and so $P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B)$